# Angular InterpolateProvider Not Working (Custom Delimiters)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've tired numerous iterations of the $interpolateProvider example code and have had zero success creating custom delimiters for templating.  The below is a simple example of this that does not work.  Can anyone help identify the issue?  Or is this a potential issue with Angular version? Much appreciated.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) 

{
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, [[name]]
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config part looks fine, I think you might need to set the `ng-app` properly?

should be

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```